# How to Improve The axios.spread

Tags: vuejs2, axios

The below code i use for doing multiple HTTP calls depending on the `studentList`.

It works well; however, I think the axios spread is not necessary

```
export default {

      getFee (studentList: { studentId: string }[]) {

        if (studentList.length < 1) {
          Promise.resolve()
        }
        let promises = []
        for (const student of studentList) {
          if (!student.studentId) {
            Promise.resolve()
          }
          var url = `${API_URL}/${student.studentId}`

          promises.push(Axios.get(url))
        }

        return Axios.all(promises)
          .then(Axios.spread((...args) => {
            // customise the response here
            return args
              .map(response => response.data)
              .map(data => {
                // @ts-ignore
                data.totalMark = data.markinPhysics + data.markinMaths + data.markinChemistry // total mark  sum of marks in differnet discplines
                return data
              })
          }))
          .catch(error => {
            switch (error.response.status) {
              case 400:
                console.log('student not found')
                break
              case 500:
                console.log('error invoking')

                break
              default:
                console.log('unknown error')
```

I have to do multiple network calls in Vue and I am using Axios.

I got it working by axios, all and axios.spread, but I think the code can be improved.

The logic is to do multiple calls for the student list and get the outputs back

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Axios.all

as well as [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) accepts array of promises and returns a new Promise which is resolved whenever all of the given promises are resolved with an array with the result of each promise

e.g.

```
const promise1 = Promise.resolve('data1');
const promise2 = Promise.resolve('data2');

Promise.all([
  promise1,
  promise2,
]).then(results => {
  // results is an array with 2 elements
  console.log(results[0]); // data1
  console.log(results[1]); // data2
});
```

you can use Axios.spread to to assign each result to a variable like this:

```
Promise.all([
  promise1,
  promise2,
]).then(Axios.spread(( result1, result2 ) => {
  // args is an array with 2 elements
  console.log(result1); // data1
  console.log(result2); // data2
});
```

alternatively you can use [ES6 Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
Promise.all([
  promise1,
  promise2,
]).then(([ result1, result2 ]) => {
  // args is an array with 2 elements
  console.log(result1); // data1
  console.log(result2); // data2
});
```

## Unnecessary Promise.resolve()

Your Promise.resolve() function calls have no effect on the getFee method since you're not returning them

#### What would my implementation be

```
async function getFee(studentList) {
  try {
    const promises = studentList.reduce((acc, student) =>
      student.studentId
        ? acc.concat(Axios.get(`${API_URL}/${student.studentId}`))
        : acc
    , []);

    const responses = await Axios.all(promises);

    return responses
      .map(response => response.data)
      .map(data => ({
        // return new object
        // with data's properties
        // instead of assinging the new ones directly to the data
        ...data,
        // total mark  sum of marks in differnet discplines
        totalMark: data.markinPhysics + data.markinMaths + data.markinChemistry,
      }));
  } catch (error) {
    switch (error.response.status) {
      case 400:
        console.log("student not found");
        break;
      case 500:
        console.log("error invoking");
        break;
      default:
        console.log("unknown error");
    }
  }
}

export default {
  getFee
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're only using `args` as an array, you could remove `axios.spread`.

`axios.spread()` might only be useful in older browsers now that ES2015 introduced its own [*spread* operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). The main purpose of `axios.spread()` is to expand the result of `axios.all()` into an argument list, such that you could do:

```js
axios.all(promiseArray).then(axios.spread(function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
  /*...*/
}))
```

instead of:

```js
axios.all(promiseArray).then(function(args) {
  var arg1 = args[0]
  var arg2 = args[1]
  var arg3 = args[2]
  /*...*/
})
```

ES2015's [*rest* operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) does the inverse of `axios.spread()`, so when you combine them (as seen below), you end up with the result above, as if `axios.spread()` and the *rest* operator weren't even used:

```js
axios.all(promiseArray).then(axios.spread(function(...args) {
  var arg1 = args[0]
  var arg2 = args[1]
  var arg3 = args[2]
  /*...*/
}))

// or newer syntax:

axios.all(promiseArray).then(axios.spread((...args) => {
  const arg1 = args[0]
  const arg2 = args[1]
  const arg3 = args[2]
  /*...*/
}))
```

Comment: Yes, it's the second snippet above: `axios.all(promiseArray).then(args => /*...*/)`

Answer (score 2):

To avoid promise chaining and improve readability, I think below can be used.

```
const [arg1, arg2] = await Promise.all(promises)
```